# Is a layer of gas with sufficiently large optical thickness really radiating as a black body?

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation, thermal-radiation, absorption

Can a parcel of gas with large value of optical thickness really radiate like a black body?
I have in mind a simple (most likely oversimplified) model which yields

$$I_\nu = I_\nu(0) e^{-\tau\nu} + I_\nu^B [1-e^{-\tau_\nu}]$$

It says, that radiation of a layer of optical thickness $\tau$ radiates based on

- the radiation entering on one side, attenuated by absorption
- the intrinsic radiation, also attenuated by absorption

I have seen this equation in several books. But I do not understand the quantity $J_\nu$ in the equation

$$d I\lambda = -k_\lambda \rho I_\lambda ds + j_\lambda \rho ds$$

which is replaced after introducing the source function $J_\lambda=j_\lambda/k_\lambda$ by

$$\frac{d I\lambda(s)}{k_\lambda \rho ds} = -I_\lambda(s) + J_\lambda(s)$$

In my textbook, a few sentences after having introduced this, it is said, that

$$J_\lambda(s) = B_\lambda^B(T)$$

where $B_\lambda^B(T)$ is the Planck-Function. I cannot follow this argument: It would mean, that an absorbing gas with sufficiently big optical thickness radiates to the outside according to Planck's law - but by what argument this assumption is justified?

See here the original text:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps one of the answers here will help: [How does radiation become black-body radiation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/645671/247642)

Comment: this study of the radiation of the atmosphere might interest you and show the coplexity of the problem with gases https://www.acs.org/climatescience/atmosphericwarming/earthatmosphere.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression $J_{\nu} = B_\nu$ (where $J_\nu$ is the source function) is true for a source of thermal radiation that is in [local thermodynamic equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_equilibrium#Local_and_global_equilibrium).  i.e. Where the population  of various energy levels and the speeds of particles are determined by a *single* temperature. This is just Kirchoff's law of thermal radiation.

If that is the case, then you can see from the equation of radiative transfer (the first equation you have written), that when $\tau_\nu$, the optical depth, becomes large, then the specific intensity, $I_\nu \rightarrow B_\nu$.

So it is indeed true that if you have a sufficiently thick slab (and by this we mean optically thick, with large $\tau_\nu$), then the specific intensity from the slab will approach the Planck function value. Of course for the emergent spectrum to resemble the Planck function then this must be true at all frequencies. The emergent spectrum will in fact be the Planck function at the temperature at which the optical depth to the surface is $\sim 2/3$ and the radiation can escape.

Note that the emission of a blackbody spectrum is *not* a property of the gas/material alone, it is a combination of thermal emission (the $J_\nu = B_\nu$ part) *and* the geometry (size and density) of the system

Edit: Incidentally, the notation you are using is very confusing. Usually $S_\nu$ is used for the source function and $J_\nu$ is the mean specific intensity. The confusing thing is that for a blackbody, $S_\nu = B_\nu = I_\nu = J_\nu$ !

Comment: this has important consequences for the radiation given off by an atomic bomb, in that after the release of the initial UV/X-ray/gamma flash, the expanding fireball is effectively opaque and cannot get rid of its energy radiatively until it expands far enough to reduce its optical depth so it can radiate away the trapped heat inside. This yields a second flash  (of longer duration) after the first flash.

Comment: ProfRob: Thanks, but I still didn't get the point why a sufficiently thick slab of gas in LTE radiates as a black body. J=B follows from this, but why is it true in the first place? The assumption appears to me without having a ground. Is it just, because a thick slab absorbs everything? A thin slab wouldn't. So do the property of a slab in terms of having Black body characteristic or not depend on its thickness? This would mean, this property is not an intrinsic property of the gas "itself", but rather of geometry.

Comment: @MichaelW Blackbody radiation is NOT a property of the gas and it is geometry-dependent. There is a close to perfect blackbody radiation field in the solar interior. A cubic centimetre of solar interior extracted and viewed with a spectrograph would look nothing like a blackbody. As for why J=B, this is just detailed balance and Kirchoff's law.